# SSH client for Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, ssh, sftp

I want an App for Mac OS X 10.5 to connect to my site using ssh. The app must be free and have some sort of instructions to get me started.

EDIT:

I just needed to take care of something on my website via SSH. CyberDuck worked.

Comment: Given the first two answers that refer to file transfers rather than plain SSH access (which is included in OS X; just type `ssh` in Terminal): please explain what you need?

Comment: so actually you want a 'scp' client and not interactivity?

Comment: @edit2 statement: yah, but now the question reflects correctly what you accepted as an answer. 'take care of something with ssh' is an open field.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/), a free, open-source app. Here are the supported protocols:

> FTP (File Transfer Protocol), FTP/TLS
>   (FTP secured over SSL/TLS), **SFTP (SSH
>   Secure File Transfer)**, WebDAV
>   (Web-based Distributed Authoring and
>   Versioning), Amazon S3 and Rackspace
>   Cloud Files.

Comment: Cyberduck costs money when downloaded from the Mac App Store. It's still freely downloadable from the website though, and only shows a message in the title bar if you don't have a "donation key". Other than that, it's full-featured, unlimited, and doesn't nag. The source code is also available, if you want to change or remove this reminder.

Answer (score 2):

Transmit (Panic software) has that functionality.

Comment: but it's not free

Answer (score 2):

Another great one I recommend (Open Source) is **FileZilla**

http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/).

You can use [Macfusion](http://www.macfusionapp.org/), but it's not been updated for a while.

Comment: Any hints on why I got a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

There is also [RBrowser](http://www.rbrowser.com/):

[image]

> Easy-to-use FTP - SFTP/**SSH** Remote File
>   Management, File Transfers and Folder
>   Synchronization.
>
> Who is RBrowser for? Anybody who has
>   accounts on remote UNIX systems of
>   whatever flavor, or on any host that
>   has an FTP server. Working on
>   documents, managing files over the
>   network can be fairly painful,
>   especially for those who are not
>   experts in the cryptic UNIX shell
>   commands. If you work on remote
>   systems or have to move files back and
>   forth often, RBrowser can make your
>   life a lot easier. RBrowser provides
>   an easy way to manage and edit your
>   HTML pages on the directly on the
>   remote WEB host. RBrowser provides
>   connectivity with FTP and SFTP.
>   Maintain your web pages and sync the
>   changes with a single click! Backup
>   your important files using the Folder
>   Sync Engine in RBrowser!

Comment: Only the screenshot is old, the software has been updated and has Leopard/Snow Leopard support.